# How to set hidden inputs data attribute based on dropdown selection in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am really trying to get a better rating for this question and I have tried laying it out as descriptively as I can and following the Stack Overflow standards for a good question. Any advice on how I can improve this question would be greatly appreciated. I am really trying my best to improve this. Please help. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Below is the question :

The objective at the time was to set a custom attribute based on a selected select box option.

Here's the HTML for a select box :

```
<select id="select-box">
  <option value="0">Option 1</option>
  <option value="1">Option 2</option>
  <option value="2">Option 3</option>
</select>
<input type="number" name="option_sku" id="option-sku" data-sku="">
```

And the Jquery :

```
// if the selected option is set to 0, 1 or 2 
// then it must set a value to the hidden input field.

I tried this :
if('#select-box' == 1){
 // Set the data attribute here : 
 '#option-sku'.sku('Option 1 Name');
}
```

However, this code wasn't working as expected. When an option was selected from the dropdown, I wanted to set the sku attribute of the hidden input field to a specific value corresponding to the selection.
But no values were been set.

Is there an issue with how I was trying to access the selected value and set the custom attribute SKU.

If anyone has a great solution for this please post your answer below.

Comment: `'#track_type_selected'` is a string. It's never going to be equal to `1`.

Comment: so how can set my input attribute to the required attribute based on the selected option? i need to get it from the selected option

Comment: the code I'm trying to make adds products to a shopping cart through the use of a requirements calculator. so basically i need the sku to bet set so it can add the correct product

Comment: Are you using jquery as well?

Comment: yes i am :) "Wordpress"

Comment: You should learn the basics of JS when working with DOM. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_value.asp

Comment: Ok cool I see whats happening. Thanks for the feedback. that link is really helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before i go on with the solution, i can understand that you have basic to zero knowledge about JavaScript.. make sure you understand how JavaScript syntax works then continue.

To get the selected option use this code:

`var e = document.getElementById("track_type_selected");
var selectedIndex = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;`

`selectedIndex` variable should now include the current selected index. (1,2,3.. etc)

So you can do this:
`if(selectedIndex==1){/* some code */}`

Now, to get sku attribute (since you confirmed that you use jquery) you can do this:
`$("#required_tracks_id").attr("sku");`

Make sure you check .attr usage and edit it to your needs.